# WPF Toolkit - February 2010 Release

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to install the new release of the WPFToolkit, no success...
iv'e followed the instructions at codeplex - first uninstall the previous version and then install the new one, but still, after i reference the new version, i get to use the previous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 dir "\Program Files\WPF Toolkit"
```

Mine says `v3.5.50211.1`

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386010/unable-to-add-autocompletebox-to-toolbox-or-handcrafting-xaml/2386229#2386229).