# Unable to add AutoCompleteBox to toolbox or handcrafting XAML

Tags: c#, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I'm trying to use the AutoCompleteBox control from the february release of WPFToolkit.

I install the toolkit using the .msi file, add the assembly reference, and only two new controls appears in my toolbox: Calendar and Datepicker.
I then tried to handcraft the XAML as shown in [WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again/2380365#2380365), but once again, the AutoCompleteBox is missing.

Also, since I've installed WPFToolkit, my toolbox has some strange behavior, like deleting all elements and not letting me add any new control.

Does anyone have had the same issues, and know how to solve them?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Within VS right click on the Toolbox
2. Select "`Reset Toolbox`".

**If that doesn't work:**

1. Stop Visual Studio
2. Go to: `&lt;drive&gt;:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\&lt;VS version&gt;`
3. Delete the hidden files:

   - `toolbox.tbd`
   - `toolbox_reset.tbd`
   - `toolboxIndex.tbd`
   - `toolboxIndex_reset.tbd`
4. Start Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, I managed to get my old controls back in the toolbox, but still just Calendar and DatePicker show up.

Also, these are the only ones from WPFToolkit present in the list displayed when I choose which elements I want in the toolbox.

Comment: Are you looking in the right spot?  I couldn't find it at first.  The AutoCompleteBox is in the `DataVisualization` category.  see the image here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again/2339036#2339036

Comment: Well ... despite having installed WPFToolit, I don't have a DataVisualization category in my toolbox. I only have Common, Controls, and General. (Translated from a french VS, so I hope the names are the same in english :/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You probably still need to add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit. That fixed it for me.